# Which control should be use

Tags: telerik, report, controls

I am using Telerik to make report. I want create a report has area like image below

[image]

Which control I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify in which context you are working with Telerik Reporting. However, does not make sense to add a progress-bar in the report itself and moreover there are no controls available for such function in the Reporting controls that you can add. You could eventually work on the Report-viewer progress message but looking at your pic this does not sound that will meet what you have in mind.

Would it be much more convenient to add the progress bar on the form or page outside the Report viewer and then use any progress bar control. Eventually hide the Report-viewer until the data and are fully loaded. I have no samples for Telerik reporting/Telerik Report Viewer but [here](http://our.componentone.com/2013/05/20/how-to-show-a-progress-bar-in-activereports/) you can see a simple made on another controls suits.

Comment: First I apologize for the question not clear. My desire is make a report about complete task. It progress-bar use to show percentage of completed task. Hope get help from you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of Telerik controls for ASP.NET Web Forms, you can use the new RadProgressBar control.

"The Telerik ASP.NET Progress Bar is a lightweight customizable control that allows you to visualize the progress of an operation such as a download, file transfer, level of completion of a form or any other measurable process."

Link: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/progress-bar/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am working on MVC. I didn't see RadProgressBar on Tool bar

Comment: No problem, you could use the jQuery UI Progressbar instead. It's pretty clean and straightforward to use. http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/